# Postgresql: наличие элемента в массиве jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Подскажите, как правильно сделать. Внутри моей функции PostgreSQL есть место, где мне необходимо узнать, существует ли элемент массива в данном массиве jsonb

```
/* Некая строка преобразуемая в jsonb */    
z = '["3861a9bd-1ff2-4feb-860e-49b4d70eefa0","13e6b1b4-4f75-5bb4-f90d-b79bc693792f"]'::jsonb;

/* Как узнать входит ли значение типа uuid = 3861a9bd-1ff2-4feb-860e-49b4d70eefa0 в мой этот 
массив? как то через */ 

SELECT count(value) as k FROM jsonb_array_elements_text( z ) 
where z @> my_uuid_var::jsonb into q; 

/* но у меня логика не совсем правильная. Вернет либо 0 - если нет в массиве, либо полное 
количество элементов массива, а это избыточно, достаточно позиции в массиве или просто 1. 
при этом uuid напрямую к jsonb не приводится :( */
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array